# Is there a way to prompt git to redo a diff on a conflicted file?

Tags: git, diff

I have done a merge of two branches in git and diffs of some (rather large) source files contain all of the HEAD code followed by all of the branch code like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
// All of the head
=======
// All of the devel
>>>>>>> devel
```

I suspect that this is because of inconsistent line endings (opening the file in an editor gives warning that the endlines are inconsistent) in the two different branches. The question is, is there a way to ask the git to reprocess the diff after I normalize the endlines?

Answer (score 0):

You could undo your attempt to merge, fix endlines, and do it again:

```
git reset --hard
vim #fix endlines
git merge devel
```

Of course, you may want to avoid it if you already solved a few conflicts, since they would be reset by the first step.